# How to solve the singularly perturbed problem below

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, boundary-layer

There is a singularly perturbed problem:

\begin{align}
&\epsilon u''(x) + u(x) - u^2(x)=0,\quad x<0<1,\\
& u(0)=1, \quad u(1)=0.
\end{align}

where $\epsilon \ll 1$ is a tiny parameter. From the numerical result, it has a boundary layer at $x=1$ (The graph below is the numerical solution).
I would like to find the asymptotic solution with the method of matched asymptotic expansions, but I have no idea how to deal with such a nonlinear problem.

Could anyone give me some hints? Of course, other methods or the exact solution are also available.

[image]

Here, I post the analytic result that I get until now (haven't finished yet).
Consider the matched asymptotic expansion.

**Step1: Outer Solution**

Assume that the solution can be expanded in powers of $\epsilon$, namely,
$$u(x,\epsilon)=u_0(x)+\epsilon u_1(x) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$
Substituting this into original problem and consider the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ equation, that is $\epsilon=0$, we get
\begin{align}
& u_0^2(x)-u_0(x)=0, \\
& u_0(0)=1.
\end{align}
We know that $u_0(x)=1$ is a or solution. From the graph above, it is reasonable.

**Step2: Boundary Layer**

Based on the numerical result, there is a boundary layer at $x=1$, so the stretching transformation we take is
$$\bar x = \frac{x-1}{\delta}. $$

From the stretching transformation and the chain rule, we have that
$$\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{1}{\delta}\frac{d}{d \bar x}.$$

Let the $U(\bar x)$ be the solution using the stretching transformation, then the original problem becomes
\begin{align}
&\frac{\epsilon}{\delta^2}U''(\bar x)+U(\bar x)-U^2(\bar x)=0, \\
&U(0)=0.
\end{align}
The boundary condition comes from the fact that $u(1)=U(\frac{1-1}{\delta})=U(0)=0.$
The domainant balances illustrates $\frac{\epsilon}{\delta^2}=1$, namely,
$$\epsilon = \delta^2. $$
Thus, the transformed problem becomes
\begin{align}
&U''(\bar x)+U(\bar x)-U^2(\bar x)=0, \\
&U(0)=0.
\end{align}
After solving the equation above, we may get the solution that includes a parameter $c$. Then, matching the solution of boundary layer and outer solution may get the parameter $c$, and obtain the final asymptotic solution. But I have no idea how to solve the equation above.

Answer (score 1):

You get a center around $u=0$ and a saddle point around $u=1$. To get at least one-sided convergence the solution has to follow the level curve of the saddle point,
$$
ϵu'^2+u^2-\frac23u^2=\frac13.
$$
This gives $u'(1)=\pm\frac1{\sqrt{3ϵ}}$, giving an IVP for this curve. This solution will not exactly meet $u(0)=1$, only come very close to it, with an error of the form $e^{-c/\sqrtϵ}$ which is smaller than any power of $ϵ$ asymptotically for $ϵ\to0$.

This should however be good enough for a first approximation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I drew the graph according to your answer, and the solution is $u(x)=sin(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{3\epsilon}})$. It is indeed a good approximation. This problem, however, has several solutions. One of them is shown in the graph that I added above. So I would like to ask how can I get the asymptotic solution shown in the graph? sorry for the unclear question before. 
By the way, how can I get the level curve of the saddle point that you post? I study the numerical stuff and have little knowledge about the analytic one.